# Error in pom.xml file directly after creating project using AWS Toolkit

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3

I tried to work on some AWS S3 implementations and wanted to start off with the provided examples of the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse.
I created the project as following:

[Project Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZDjC.png)

Then right afterwards i get an error in the pom.xml right at line 1 and 13.

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>samples</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.497</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

```html
Failure to transfer com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.11.22 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the 
 update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.11.22 from/to central (https://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.11.22 from 
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: 
 Could not transfer artifact com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.11.22 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. at 
 org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:240) at 
 org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:208) at 
 org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:563) at 
 org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:481) at 
 org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399) at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:
 224) at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:338) at 
 org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202) at 
 org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:212) at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:185) at 
 org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:116) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:628) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:525) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.lambda$1(ProjectRegistryManager.java:489) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:488) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:349) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:296) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.configureNewMavenProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:259) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$4.run(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:528) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.AbstractRunnable.call(AbstractRunnable.java:26) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.AbstractRunnable.call(AbstractRunnable.java:1) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1336) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.enableMavenNature(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:525) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createSimpleProject(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:709) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createSimpleProject(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:662) at 
 com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.maven.MavenFactory.createMavenProject(MavenFactory.java:76) at 
 com.amazonaws.eclipse.sdk.ui.wizard.NewAwsJavaProjectWizard.doFinish(NewAwsJavaProjectWizard.java:215) at 
 com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.plugin.AbstractAwsProjectWizard$1$1.execute(AbstractAwsProjectWizard.java:63) at 
 org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.lambda$0(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:110) at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2295) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2322) at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:131) at 
 com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.plugin.AbstractAwsProjectWizard$1.run(AbstractAwsProjectWizard.java:70) at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:
 122)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check you settings.xml in Maven... this is to check if Maven would look for private repository or public one & make sure if it's a private repo like Nexus, you're connected to VPN..
then right click on the project & then Maven, the check force update of snapshots/ release & click OK..